Error with scikit-learn 0.23.0 while building a python docker image
this is the python version
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.9

this is the version used in the library that failed
scikit-learn==0.23.0

error that shows in console at some moment of the build:
> 1177.9   × Building wheel for scikit-learn (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
> 1177.9   │ exit code: 1
> 1177.9   ╰─> [28 lines of output]
> 1177.9       <string>:12: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
> 1177.9       Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
> 1177.9       Traceback (most recent call last):
> 1177.9         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
> 1177.9           main()
> 1177.9         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
> 1177.9           json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
> 1177.9         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
> 1177.9           return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
> 1177.9         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-dsi_2smv/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 438, in build_wheel
> 1177.9           return _build(['bdist_wheel', '--dist-info-dir', str(metadata_directory)])
> 1177.9         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-dsi_2smv/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 426, in _build
> 1177.9           return self._build_with_temp_dir(
> 1177.9         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-dsi_2smv/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 407, in _build_with_temp_dir
> 1177.9           self.run_setup()
> 1177.9         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-dsi_2smv/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 522, in run_setup
> 1177.9           super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
> 1177.9         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-dsi_2smv/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 320, in run_setup
> 1177.9           exec(code, locals())
> 1177.9         File "<string>", line 304, in <module>
> 1177.9         File "<string>", line 296, in setup_package
> 1177.9         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-dsi_2smv/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 26, in <module>
> 1177.9           from numpy.distutils.command import config, config_compiler, \
> 1177.9         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-dsi_2smv/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/command/config.py", line 20, in <module>
> 1177.9           from numpy.distutils.mingw32ccompiler import generate_manifest
> 1177.9         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-dsi_2smv/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/mingw32ccompiler.py", line 34, in <module>
> 1177.9           from distutils.msvccompiler import get_build_version as get_build_msvc_version
> 1177.9       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.msvccompiler'
> 1177.9       [end of output]
> 1177.9
> 1177.9   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> 1177.9   ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-learn

I tried to build a docker image and it failed
